# How can I show a category name in html dropdown list?

Tags: html, select, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown list in a form. There are many items. I want to show the category names in the dropdown list which the users will be able to see but won't be able to select.

So far I have this. But obviously it is not working.

```
<select id="item_name" name="item_name">
                    <dl>
                        <dt>Category 1</dt>
                            <dd><option value="1">Item 1</option></dd>
                            <dd><option value="2">Item 2</option></dd>
                            <dd><option value="3">Item 3</option></dd>
                        <dt>Category 2</dt>
                            <dd><option value="4">Item 4</option></dd>
                            <dd><option value="5">Item 5</option></dd>
                            <dd><option value="6">Item 6</option></dd>
                    </dl>
                </select>
```

Comment: What gave you the impression that you could use a `<dl>` element within a `<select>` element?

Comment: I just tried to see whether it works or not. But obviously it doesn't.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use [`optgroup` elements](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#the-optgroup-element):

```
<select>
    <optgroup label="Category 1">
        <option>Item 1</option>
        <option>Item 2</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Category 2">
        <option>Item 3</option>
        <option>Item 4</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

[Example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tykhQ/)

Answer (score 2):

html optgroup?

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_optgroup

```
<select name="whatever">
  <optgroup label="Category 1">
    <option value="1.1">Item 1.1</option>
    <option value="1.2">Item 1.2</option>
    <option value="1.3">Item 1.3</option>
    <option value="1.4">Item 1.4</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Category 2">
    <option value="2.1">Item 2.1</option>
    <option value="2.2">Item 2.2</option>
    <option value="2.3">Item 2.3</option>
    <option value="2.4">Item 2.4</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: Are you asking him if its an answer or are you telling him its an answer?

Comment: *hint*: fix the link to point to **any** other reference, and I'll up-vote your answer.

Comment: @zzzzBov: Whatever.  When I need a quick reference to something w3cschools is usually good enough.  Totally accurate: no.  But then neither is original sources like w3c itself wrt actual implementations. Marketing slimy-ness?  Definitely -- but we all ought to have our adult pants on when surfing the web these days.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the definition of the select element:

http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/select

It does not allow for `<dl>` to be present inside a select drop down. You might be able to achieve this effect using style properties for those options that you know are categories.